# Ensure combo of values are unique, but entered any number of times - Mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design

How can I enforce constraint checks to ensure that a given combination of values are unique, but can be entered any number of times?

Example: I have two columns: `Group_ID` and `Group_Name`. So all data with `Group_ID = 1` will always have `Group_Name as 'Test1'`. What I want to prevent is someone entering `'Test2'` into `Group_Name` where `Group_ID=1`. This should fail the insert. All this data is loaded directly into the DB without any UI, hence I cannot enforce these checks in application. So what I need is:

A unique constraint over multiple columns, but only for the given combination without checking how many times they have been entered.

Is there anything built in Mysql to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should normalize your table a little bit. The `group_id`,`group_name` pair should be in a separate table that defines your groups and then the table you're working with should only have `group_id`. Then you could add a foreign key from your table to the group table to ensure that your `group_id` values reference real groups.

If you can't normalize your tables then you'll probably have to use a before insert and before update trigger to ensure that `Group_ID` and `Group_Name` always come together as required.